# Issue with appcmd when attempting to list site and apppool

Tags: windows, iis

As part of a server migration, I am attempting to export the IIS configurations from the existing server.  The result was a new one on me presenting me with the following outputs for the commands.

```
.\appcmd apppool list
Object 'LIST' is not supported.  Run 'appcmd.exe /?' to display supported objects.

.\appcmd site list 
Object 'LIST' is not supported.  Run 'appcmd.exe /?' to display supported objects.
```

Has anyone encountered (and hopefully resolved) this one before?  In case it helps, the source server is Windows 2008 R2 Standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ugh...  so it turns out that this was user error on my part.  Correct commands below for those that are interested and to ensure that my shame lives on.

```
.\appcmd list apppool /config /xml

.\appcmd list site /config /xml
```